# R function not producing answer, but doing steps manually works...?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, for-loop, correlation

The function takes specific files in a directory, accesses the length after omitting incomplete data rows and then, if the total rows is at or above a threshold, place a `cor()` value into a vector and return that vector.

code:

```
  corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0){

    files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
    vector <- c()

    for (i in 1:number of files in directory) {
        file <- read.csv(files_list[i])
        file_noNA <- na.omit(file)

    if(nrow(file_noNA) >= threshold){
        x <- file_noNA$column1
        y <- file_noNA$column2
        a <- cor(x,y)
        vector <- append(vector,a)
        }
      } 
    }
```

The return is `NULL`. However, if I do each part separately, I am able to create a vector with each correlation for each file that has a data count above the threshold.

Why would the function not work, but manually work doing the steps work?

Comment: where is the `return()` statement? at the end of the function you sould put `return(vector)`, don't you think?

Comment: You don't need an explicit return, but the function does return the last evaluated expression.

Comment: Without a return statement, R functions return the result of the last calculation.  You need return(vector), otherwise, it returns the last calculated value, which may not be vector since vector is inside an if statement.  Also, you should check if your variable names override existing functions, like vector, that could create unexpected results.  Before using a new variable, just type the name in the command window to see if there is an existing function with that name.  Change variable vector to vec, but check if vec is a function in your packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an explicit return statement, R functions return the result of the last calculation.  This function needs an explicit return.  I would try the following, but notice that the function name was changed from corr to mycorr.

Generate some sample data files, and cor results for checking function

```
nFiles = 10
NCols=2
for (ii in seq(1,nFiles)) {
  NRows = sample(5:30,1)
  fname = paste("data\\test_",ii,".txt",collapse="")
  myMat <- matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
  write.table(myMat, file=fname, row.names=FALSE, col.names=c("column1","column2"), sep="\t")
  print(paste("File ",fname,"has",NRows,"rows with cor of"))
  print(cor(myMat))
  flush.console()
}
```

Here is the function

```
myCorr <- function(myDir, threshold = 0){

  files_list <- list.files(myDir, full.names=TRUE)
  mv <- c()

  for (i in seq(1:length(files_list))) {
    file <- read.csv(files_list[i],sep="")
    file_noNA <- na.omit(file)

    if(nrow(file_noNA) >= threshold){
      x <- file_noNA$column1
      y <- file_noNA$column2
      a <- cor(x,y)
      mv<- c(mv,a)
    }
  }
  return(mv)
}
```

Run the function, compare output to previous output.  Can adjust the row threshold to check.

```
myDir = "data"
myCorr(myDir)
```

Comment: I missed renaming vector in the mv<-... statement.  Try it again in a few seconds.

Comment: If it still doesn't work. what do your files look like?

Comment: I edited the example to include generating sample data, for checking the results.  Also corrected some minor errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is no return statement. You can return by calling the `return(.)` function, or by default the last expression in the function will be the return statement.

You can also make the code more R like:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0){
    files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)

    na.omit(sapply(files_list, function(fname)
            {
                file <- read.csv(fname)
                file_noNA <- na.omit(file)
                if (nrow(file_noNA) >= threshold)
                {
                    return(with(file_noNA, cor(column1, column2)))
                }
                NA
            }))
}
```

This should be faster than creating the vector object and expanding it every iteration.

Comment: I am trying your code and not getting the solution I need. I get **Error in is.data.frame(y) : object 'column2' not found**. I edited column1 and column2 to the actual column names using ''. I left fname alone. For more clarity sake, my directory has 300 some files, if the ith file's row count without NA's is >= the threshold, that file's correlation is to be put in a vector.

Comment: Did you add quotes around column names? Lose the quotes around the column names and it should work.

Comment: The code works, but has way too much noise, the return vector should look like **-0.01896 -0.14051 -0.04390 -0.06816 -0.12351 -0.07589** as an example.

Comment: Also, when I have a threshold lower than shortest file, the code doesnt work.

Comment: Too much noise? What do you mean? It's returning a vector with attributes `names(x)` containing file names... Seems like pretty useful information to me. If you don't like that, you can do `res = corr("dir"); names(res) <- NULL`. The code does work when you set the threshold less than the shortest file... it returns a vector of length 0.

Comment: "To You". The output seems to be useful (except for listing all of my file after every execution or thresholds that return nothing). However, I specifically stated what I NEEDED to be the output and you didn't take that into account. Maube you could add all those cool details in a footnote for future reference. Also, the code doesn't return null when I don't enter a threshold. It returned a cor() for every file.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. The above code returns a vector (unless there are no objects, then returns an empty `na.omit` object, which is a type of vector). Objects in R can have attributes. This implicitly sets the `names` attribute (see `?attr`). It has no effect on the data of the vector, other than you can index the vector by its name. None of the code on this page returns `NULL` if you don't specify a threshold -- I simply recreated the original behavior you implemented. Also, one should be careful with returning `NULL`. It's behavior is different than in most programming languages.