# Error within function but not when performing steps manually in R

Tags: r

I created a function and all steps work fine when I call them manually. However, the function produces an error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 0) :
replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

This is the function:

```
my_function <- function (model = NA, order = NA) {

    # make empty list of predictions
    the_predictions <- list ()

    # get model coefficients
    coeff <- my_coeffs(model)$fixed_effects


    # get the data the model is based on (must be in the environment)
    model_data <- model.frame(model)

    # predict based on the model.
    for (i in coeff) {
        xxx <- seq (min (model_data[[i]]), max (model_data[[i]]), length.out = 120) # make continuous vector for x-axis
        print(paste("Processing variable:", i))
        a <- (summary(ggeffects::ggpredict(model, paste0(i, " [xxx]"))))
        print (a)
        the_predictions [[i]] <- ggeffects::ggpredict (model, paste0 (i, " [xxx]"))
    }

    # return resulting list of predictions
    return(the_predictions)
}
```

Where `my_coeffs` is a function (which works) to get the coefficients of a model:

```
my_coeffs <- IBL_model_coeff <- function (model) {

    # independent vars:
    # get string of model formula and split by "+"
    independ_string <-  formula(model)[[3]][2] %>% as.character() %>% str_split (pattern = " +") %>% unlist
    # remove the "+"
    independ_string <- independ_string [! independ_string %in% "+"]

    # dependent var:
    dependent_var <- formula(model)[[2]] %>% as.character()

    # random effects:
    if ("|" %in% all.names(formula (model))) {
            random_effects <- formula(model)[[3]][3] %>% as.character()
    } else {
        random_effects <- NA
    }

    return (list (response_variable = dependent_var, fixed_effects = independ_string,  random_effects = random_effects))
}
```

An example to demonstrate the problem:

```
# build a model
a_model <- lmer (mpg ~ hp + drat + (1|cyl ),
                      data = mtcars)
```

When I try to use the function on `a_model`:

```
# get coefficients
my_function (a_model)
```

I get the error as statet above:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 0) :
    replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

However, when calling each step manually, I get

```
$hp
# Predicted values of mpg

    hp | Predicted |         95% CI
-----------------------------------
 52.00 |     24.30 | [21.07, 27.52]
 87.67 |     22.69 | [19.99, 25.39]
123.34 |     21.08 | [18.68, 23.48]
159.02 |     19.47 | [17.05, 21.89]
192.31 |     17.97 | [15.26, 20.68]
227.98 |     16.36 | [13.13, 19.59]
263.66 |     14.75 | [10.86, 18.64]
335.00 |     11.53 | [ 6.12, 16.95]

Adjusted for:
* drat = 3.60
*  cyl = 0 (population-level)

$drat
# Predicted values of mpg

drat | Predicted |         95% CI
---------------------------------
2.76 |     16.80 | [13.49, 20.12]
3.03 |     17.86 | [15.00, 20.71]
3.31 |     18.91 | [16.39, 21.43]
3.58 |     19.96 | [17.59, 22.34]
3.84 |     20.95 | [18.51, 23.39]
4.11 |     22.00 | [19.30, 24.70]
4.38 |     23.05 | [19.93, 26.18]
4.93 |     25.16 | [20.94, 29.38]

Adjusted for:
*  hp = 146.69
* cyl = 0 (population-level)
```

(which is what I am aiming for). I really wonder why it doesn't work within the function. I added some `print` statements to see where the error happens. So I assume that everything works fine until `ggeffects::ggpredict` which seems to produce the error. Here I am stuck and hope that someone can help.

Similar questions such as [R function not producing answer, but doing steps manually works...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322079/r-function-not-producing-answer-but-doing-steps-manually-works) and [Why does this work as a for loop but not within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356028/why-does-this-work-as-a-for-loop-but-not-within-a-function?rq=3) were of no help since the problem in these cases was that the functions missed a `return` statement which I already included.

Comment: I added necessary boilerplate (library calls for lme4 and tidyverse (you use at least the magrittr pipe)) Your code ran without error. Have you tested your posted code and example errors out as you expected it to ? p.s. you can step through your function code by using the debug() function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I tested that exact example and it produced the error I described here. I will try the `debug()` function, thank you!

Comment: Agree with @NirGraham. The code works fine for me when attaching the necessary pkgs.

Comment: I have updated all packages (and ran into problems with updating lme4), but finally, the error persisted. I really don't know what's the problem. As I wrote, I don't get the error when I run every step by manually.

Comment: To be precise, the error now is:
`Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': replacement has 1 row, data has 0`

Comment: I solved the problem by writing `xxx` to the environment and deleting it at the end again - all within the function. This is not a good solution, since IF I alread have an object `xxx` in the environment, it will be deleted, too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated all packages? For me, it works fine:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Matrix'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     expand, pack, unpack
my_function <- function(model = NA, order = NA) {
  # make empty list of predictions
  the_predictions <- list()

  # get model coefficients
  coeff <- my_coeffs(model)$fixed_effects


  # get the data the model is based on (must be in the environment)
  model_data <- model.frame(model)

  # predict based on the model.
  for (i in coeff) {
    xxx <- seq(min(model_data[[i]]), max(model_data[[i]]), length.out = 120) # make continuous vector for x-axis
    print(paste("Processing variable:", i))
    a <- (summary(ggeffects::ggpredict(model, paste0(i, " [xxx]"))))
    print(a)
    the_predictions[[i]] <- ggeffects::ggpredict(model, paste0(i, " [xxx]"))
  }

  # return resulting list of predictions
  return(the_predictions)
}

my_coeffs <- IBL_model_coeff <- function (model) {

    # independent vars:
    # get string of model formula and split by "+"
    independ_string <-  formula(model)[[3]][2] %>% as.character() %>% str_split (pattern = " +") %>% unlist
    # remove the "+"
    independ_string <- independ_string [! independ_string %in% "+"]

    # dependent var:
    dependent_var <- formula(model)[[2]] %>% as.character()

    # random effects:
    if ("|" %in% all.names(formula (model))) {
            random_effects <- formula(model)[[3]][3] %>% as.character()
    } else {
        random_effects <- NA
    }

    return (list (response_variable = dependent_var, fixed_effects = independ_string,  random_effects = random_effects))
}

a_model <- lmer(mpg ~ hp + drat + (1 | cyl),
  data = mtcars
)

my_function(a_model)
#> [1] "Processing variable: hp"
#>        x           predicted       std.error        conf.low     
#>  Min.   : 52.0   Min.   :11.53   Min.   :1.154   Min.   : 6.119  
#>  1st Qu.:122.8   1st Qu.:14.72   1st Qu.:1.233   1st Qu.:10.819  
#>  Median :193.5   Median :17.92   Median :1.443   Median :15.194  
#>  Mean   :193.5   Mean   :17.92   Mean   :1.602   Mean   :14.627  
#>  3rd Qu.:264.2   3rd Qu.:21.11   3rd Qu.:1.903   3rd Qu.:18.701  
#>  Max.   :335.0   Max.   :24.30   Max.   :2.639   Max.   :21.074  
#>    conf.high     group  
#>  Min.   :16.95   1:120  
#>  1st Qu.:18.63          
#>  Median :20.64          
#>  Mean   :21.20          
#>  3rd Qu.:23.51          
#>  Max.   :27.52          
#> [1] "Processing variable: drat"
#>        x           predicted       std.error        conf.low    
#>  Min.   :2.760   Min.   :16.80   Min.   :1.156   Min.   :13.49  
#>  1st Qu.:3.303   1st Qu.:18.89   1st Qu.:1.212   1st Qu.:16.37  
#>  Median :3.845   Median :20.98   Median :1.359   Median :18.54  
#>  Mean   :3.845   Mean   :20.98   Mean   :1.427   Mean   :18.06  
#>  3rd Qu.:4.388   3rd Qu.:23.07   3rd Qu.:1.572   3rd Qu.:19.94  
#>  Max.   :4.930   Max.   :25.16   Max.   :2.058   Max.   :20.94  
#>    conf.high     group  
#>  Min.   :20.12   1:120  
#>  1st Qu.:21.42          
#>  Median :23.43          
#>  Mean   :23.91          
#>  3rd Qu.:26.20          
#>  Max.   :29.38
#> $hp
#> # Predicted values of mpg
#> 
#>     hp | Predicted |         95% CI
#> -----------------------------------
#>  52.00 |     24.30 | [21.07, 27.52]
#>  87.67 |     22.69 | [19.99, 25.39]
#> 123.34 |     21.08 | [18.68, 23.48]
#> 159.02 |     19.47 | [17.05, 21.89]
#> 192.31 |     17.97 | [15.26, 20.68]
#> 227.98 |     16.36 | [13.13, 19.59]
#> 263.66 |     14.75 | [10.86, 18.64]
#> 335.00 |     11.53 | [ 6.12, 16.95]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * drat = 3.60
#> *  cyl = 0 (population-level)
#> 
#> Not all rows are shown in the output. Use `print(..., n = Inf)` to show
#>   all rows.
#> 
#> $drat
#> # Predicted values of mpg
#> 
#> drat | Predicted |         95% CI
#> ---------------------------------
#> 2.76 |     16.80 | [13.49, 20.12]
#> 3.03 |     17.86 | [15.00, 20.71]
#> 3.31 |     18.91 | [16.39, 21.43]
#> 3.58 |     19.96 | [17.59, 22.34]
#> 3.84 |     20.95 | [18.51, 23.39]
#> 4.11 |     22.00 | [19.30, 24.70]
#> 4.38 |     23.05 | [19.93, 26.18]
#> 4.93 |     25.16 | [20.94, 29.38]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> *  hp = 146.69
#> * cyl = 0 (population-level)
#> 
#> Not all rows are shown in the output. Use `print(..., n = Inf)` to show
#>   all rows.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

btw, you can also return predictions for each variable in the model by just passing the model as argument:

```r
a_model <- lme4::lmer(mpg ~ hp + drat + (1 | cyl),
  data = mtcars
)
ggeffects::ggpredict(a_model)
#> $hp
#> # Predicted values of mpg
#> 
#>  hp | Predicted |         95% CI
#> --------------------------------
#>  50 |     24.39 | [21.13, 27.64]
#>  85 |     22.81 | [20.08, 25.54]
#> 120 |     21.23 | [18.81, 23.65]
#> 155 |     19.65 | [17.25, 22.05]
#> 195 |     17.85 | [15.11, 20.59]
#> 230 |     16.27 | [13.00, 19.54]
#> 265 |     14.69 | [10.77, 18.61]
#> 335 |     11.53 | [ 6.12, 16.95]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * drat = 3.60
#> *  cyl = 0 (population-level)
#> 
#> Not all rows are shown in the output. Use `print(..., n = Inf)` to show
#>   all rows.
#> 
#> $drat
#> # Predicted values of mpg
#> 
#> drat | Predicted |         95% CI
#> ---------------------------------
#> 2.60 |     16.19 | [12.56, 19.82]
#> 2.80 |     16.96 | [13.72, 20.20]
#> 3.20 |     18.50 | [15.87, 21.13]
#> 3.60 |     20.04 | [17.67, 22.41]
#> 3.80 |     20.81 | [18.39, 23.23]
#> 4.00 |     21.58 | [19.00, 24.16]
#> 4.40 |     23.12 | [19.97, 26.27]
#> 5.00 |     25.43 | [21.05, 29.81]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> *  hp = 146.69
#> * cyl = 0 (population-level)
#> 
#> Not all rows are shown in the output. Use `print(..., n = Inf)` to show
#>   all rows.
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "ggalleffects" "list"        
#> attr(,"model.name")
#> [1] "a_model"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: As commented above, despite updating the packages, I still get the same error. I copy-pasted your code and it produced the same error again. Unfortunately, I have no idea where to search for possible complications.

Comment: To be precise, the error now is:
`Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': replacement has 1 row, data has 0`

Comment: Can you paste a reproducible example with the output of your session info? Maybe another package is causing a conflict here.